# puedo llamar una variable en los parámetros de os.mkdir?

Tags: python

En este simple código para crear un nuevo directorio no logro nombrar dicho directorio con el contenido de la variable que contiene la fecha actual.

```
import os
import datetime

hoy = datetime.datetime.now()
hoy1 = (hoy.strftime('%d_%m_%Y'))

os.mkdir('/Users/###/Desktop/###/###/(hoy1)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes formar el nombre usando f-string, asi:

```
dir_name = f'/Users/###/Desktop/###/###/{hoy1}'
os.mkdir(dir_name)
```

El f-string busca nombres de variables (encerradas entre "{}") y las reemplaza con su valor.

También puedes usar "%" para lograr el mismo efecto:

```
dir_name = '/Users/###/Desktop/###/###/%s' % hoy1
os.mkdir(dir_name)
```